# Windows 8 Challenge doesn't list users who've completed Tiles Challenge

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, windows-8-challenge

Windows 8 challenge is here & live - and I can see level 1- 4 prizes have a listing for which users completed them. For tiles, however - it just mentions

> Earned by n users

[image]

Can we please have a listing similar to level 1 - 4 challenges?

Comment: +1 This is probably because they suspect this will yield a lot of users and thus the user list might not fit, as some of this options are relatively simple to obtain (simultaneously voting and editing, awarding a bounty and getting an accepted answer). Although it might be nice to bring in some of the competition and reward players winning a certain tile even more by showing there avatar, if you're able to complete one of the harder ones it's certainly nice that people know about you. If the reason was that this is because of too many users, they could show the most recent users as a solution.

Comment: we could always have a seperate page to list those, like we do on badges.

Comment: Or, keeping with the Tiles theme, have each tile actually be a _tile_, with the "live tile" showing recent completions. Then clicking on the tile would expand to the full list.

Comment: This was just done because we expected a fair number of people to complete the tile challenges, and we didn't want the page to be too cluttered. Would a single row of gravatars, corresponding to the most recent tile earners, suffice?

Comment: @Emmett that would be good for a start - is it feasible to implement nhinkle's suggestion?

Comment: @Emmett it's been a week since the contest's started, is there any update on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately we won't be able to do this for this contest. Emmett was going to have the time to see to it originally, but with yesterday's hurricane hitting NYC, priorities have shifted.

We'll definitely keep this in mind for whatever our next promo will be, though, and implement a more fine-grained display for individual stages.

Sorry.